# InvalidEmail Error does not work with reset password function - Swift and Firebase (project)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add some errors to a textfield in reset password button.

As here:

```
@IBAction func SendButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if EmailTF.text == ""
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Make sure to fill in the required text field", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
    }

    else
    {
        ref.resetPasswordForUser(EmailTF.text){ (error) -> Void in

            if error != nil
            {

                if let errorCode = FAuthenticationError(rawValue: error.code) {

                    switch (errorCode) {

                    case .UserDoesNotExist:
                        print("User Doesn't Exist")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"This user doesn't exist", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}


                    case .NetworkError:
                        print("Network Error")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Network error, check your connection", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}


                    case .InvalidEmail:
                        print("invalid email")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"invalid email", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}

                    default:
                        print("Unknown Error")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Unknown Error", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}


                    }//switch

                }//if
            }// if

            else
            {
                print("Success")
                if let Email = self.EmailTF.text{
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sucess!", message:"Password reset sent to your email address  ( \(Email) )" , preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
                }

            }//else

        }
    }//1st else



}//send button
```

Whenever I try to enter an invalid email in the text field the error email does not exist appear!
InvalidEmail case never work!

Does the invalidEmail error not work with resetpassword function?
Why is this happening? 
What's wrong?

Comment: If you works with API, first check your forget password API at postman. Is it working?

Comment: @Mohd Saleem I'm working with firebase? How can I check that? The function works correctly, BTW.